# Sails.js/Waterline: one-to-many between items in the same model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I would like to model the Connected Realms from World of Warcraft within Sails.js. Since I need only one acting as 'representative', I'd have something like this:

```
 attributes: {
        region: {
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['us', 'eu', 'kr', 'tw', 'cn']
        },
        realm: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        isSourceRealm: {
            type: 'boolean'
        }
        sourceRealm: {
            model: 'Realms'
        },
        connectedRealms: {
            collection: 'Realms',
            via: 'sourceRealm'
        }
    }
```

`isSourceRealm` would mark the realm as representative; if this is `false`, `sourceRealm` would point to the representative.

Would this work?